# On ratios of distances between parts of Penrose's triangle

Tags: geometry

In the picture below, I don't understand why the very last sentence is true. I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but I just don't see it. If we pick another point $A'$ that lies in the intersection of $1$ and $2,$ and split it into the points $A_1'$ and $A_2'$ that lie in $1$ and $2$ respectively, why is $d(E,A_1')/d(E,A_2') = d(E,A_1)/d(E,A_2)?$

[image]